# How to store random numbers in an array and output the average of them?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, numbers, int

I'm trying to make a program that outputs 30 random numbers and stores them in an array, then it needs to find the average of these 30 numbers and output that back to me. So far I have this: (Sorry if I'm bad at this, I'm brand new to programming) Would appreciate any feedback :)

```
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 30;

        int[] numbers = new int[30] { r.Next(1, 100) };
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)

        Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, 100).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

        int y = r.Next();
        int avg = (int)sum / count;

        Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", avg);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?  If you're not having a *specific* problem and would like people to review your code, this question most likely belongs on another site, like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are not populating your array `numbers`, you just have one member in it, Use the `for` loop and have `{number[i] = r.Next(1,100);}` as the body of the for loop.

Comment: Hint: you do not need the array to do what you are doing.

Comment: This code does not belong to code review because it's missing all relevant code.. this code should be debugged by the OP as well as showing all relevant code / variables and their types..

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of problems in the code. You can do it like this:

```
Random r = new Random();

int count = 30;

// Create an array with count elements.
int[] numbers = new int[count];

// Loop over each index
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // Generate and store a random number at current index
    numbers[i] = r.Next(1, 100);
}

// Calculate the average
double avg = numbers.Average();

// Print the average
Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", avg);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the array, you can just add to the sum when you've found your next number.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 30;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Find your next random number
            var newNum = r.Next(1, 100);

            // Display it
            Console.WriteLine(newNum.ToString());

            // Add it to your running total
            sum += newNum;
        };

        Console.ReadLine();
        int avg = (int)sum / count;

        Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", avg);
        Console.ReadLine();
```